# How to plot a cumulative distribution that is unfilled with full alpha?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have 2 pandas dataframes and I'm trying to plot their cumulative distributions on the same plot. I prefer the unfilled style you get with `histype=step` but for some reason the alpha is really low and I can't seem to figure out how to fix it.

```
a.hist(cumulative=True, density=True, bins=100, alpha=1, histtype='step')
b.hist(cumulative=True, density=True, bins=100, alpha=1, histtype='step')
```

[image]

Setting the alpha below 1.0 (e.g. 0.5) makes the plot even more unreadable

[image]

If I use the stepfilled style the alpha parameter seems to work as expected.

```
a.hist(cumulative=True, density=True, bins=100, alpha=1, histtype='stepfilled')
b.hist(cumulative=True, density=True, bins=100, alpha=1, histtype='stepfilled')
```

[image]

I'm using seaborn and pandas in case that helps. Anyone know what's causing this weird behavior or how to work around it?

Comment: I discovered the issue was with seaborn. I had run `sns.set_style('white')` at some point which caused this behavior somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this is a strange side effect of using seaborn `set_style` and I was only able to fix it by running seaborn's `reset_orig` function.

[image]